# Traversing from Bookmark Hashtags (#bookmark) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal, jquery-traversing

I am having trouble traversing from a bookmark has tag in jquery. Specifically, the following HTML:

```
<a id="comment-1"></a> 
<div class="comment"> 
<h2 class="title"><a href="#comment-1">1st Post</a></h2> 
  <div class="content">
    <p>this is 1st reply to the original post</p> 
  </div> 
  <div class="test">1st post second line</div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to traverse to where the class = "title", if the page is landed on with a bookmark hashtag in the URL (site.com/test.html#comment-1). The following is my code I'm using for testing:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
alert ($(window.location.hash).nextAll().html());
}
```

It executes fine, and returns the appropriate html (`<h2 class="title"><a href="#co...`)

The problem is if I add a selector to it (`$(window.location.hash).next('.title').html()` ) I get a null result. Why is this so? Is nextAll not the correct Traversing function? (I've also tried next+find to no avail)

Thanks!

Comment: umm, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is if I add a selector to it ($(window.location.hash).next('.title').html() ) I get a null result, rather than actually selecting <h2 class="title"> - What I am trying to do is display/hide some of page content if there is a bookmark hash tag in the URL - i.e. only display comment-1 if it is present in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$('#comment-1')` selector selects the `<a>` element. The `next` method looks at the next sibling node of that element. There is no such node with a class of "title", so you get an empty result. In your example, the only sibling node of `<a>` is the div with class="comment". To find the `<h2 class="title">` element, you can use e.g.:

```
$(window.location.hash).next().children('.title')
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight - I therefore used the find() to fix this issue:

$(window.location.hash).next().find('.title')

Answer (score 3):

there is a jquery plugin for that: http://github.com/shanbady/Jquery-ajaxBookmarkable